# How to make Dropbox sort folder then files on OS X (web app)?

Tags: mac, dropbox

This exists only on Mac OS X. When I use Dropbox on both Windows and Linux, files and folders are sorted logically: first folders, then files.

On OS X it is weird. Whatever sorting you apply, it does not want to apply "folders first" sorting.

[image]

Am I missing something or this cannot be changed on OS X? It's weird as I think it was not such sorting 3-4 months ago.

Comment: 'Logically' is not really the term for it, 'preference' or 'because you're used to it' might be closer to the mark. Personally I abhor how Windows sorts like that - can never find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can go into Finder Preferences, go into the "Advanced" tab and check the box that says "Keep folders on top when sorting by name". 
Hope this helps.

Comment: btw, that's Sierra only. Can't be done on anything earlier.

Comment: Ooh. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Changing Finder settings won't matter because this is about dropbox.com and not when using Finder. Dropbox.com has been sorting this way for years and years.

Your only option right now is to make dropbox.com think you aren't on a Mac by changing the user agent.

If using Google Chrome you have two options. For a temporary but technical solution, you can open Developer Tools. Then click the three dot menu, go to *More Tools* and select *Network conditions*. From there you can change the user agent to Internet Explorer. Unfortunately this setting clears after you closer Developer Tools.

A second option in Chrome is to download an extension that changes your user agent. Depending on which one you get it will stay that way each time you visit dropbox.com. Head to the Chrome Store to get started with that and search for *user agent*.

Comment: Beautiful! Overriding user agent worked to change back to normal sorting on dropbox web.